# Reordering Columns with OrdinalPosition in Access table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an imported Excel spreadsheet and have added new fields to the end of the table. I know it is possible to simply re-order the fields manually, but I'd like to automate it for every import.

This is the code I have been playing with, but the table does not update with the defined `OrdinalPosition` for the column I am trying to move. I want to later apply this same technique for multiple columns.

```
Sub ReorderColumns()
    Dim db As Database
    Dim td As TableDef
    Dim NewField As Field

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set td = db.TableDefs("Imported Pcard")

    td.Fields("Postal Code").OrdinalPosition = 2

    td.Fields.Refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: As I understand the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/field-ordinalposition-property-dao), this property only determines the field order of **Recordsets** opened from the table. Not the order in table design.

Comment: Your code without the final `Refresh` works in my testing (admittedly only tested with Access 2007). Do you receive any error messages? Is the table open when you attempt to change the order?

Comment: No error message? I had to modify code to declare db and td as DAO objects. Then code works. Without Refresh line.

Comment: I am working in Access 2016 and did not get any error messages. I have closed the table before running the module.

Comment: @June7, the DAO declaration worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly declare db and td as DAO objects.

```
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim td As DAO.TableDef
```

Refresh method is not needed.